# How much does the house in Riften cost?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want the house in Riften, but I'm not sure if the price range is just the seller trying to scam me or if it automatically upgrades part of my house.  What is the price of the house and if it's a range, does paying a higher price provide any house upgrades?

Answer (score 9):

You can buy it for as little as 8000 *if* that's all you have. It won't go higher than 12000, but the only way to get a lower price is if you only have less money. The price will be all of your money as long as it's between 8000 and 12000. Paying more or less won't affect the state of the house - no upgrades come with it either way.

(Note: The same applies to Hjerim in Windhelm, but no others.)

Comment: No need to comment, you can edit that into your post! :)

Comment: Oh, OK. I was just thinking since it wasn't part of the actual answer to the question, I'd put it as a comment to separate it. I'll do that though. :)

Comment: It never hurts to add more information!

Comment: Will keep that in mind. :)